# Disable reloader of gunicorn flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, heroku, gunicorn

When I run the flask server in local machine, I use this code

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port,debug=False,use_reloader=False)
```

I am using BackgroundScheduler so I need reloader to be false othrwise BackgroundScheduler will run twice.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
```

When I deploy to Heroku, I use gunicorn like this

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

So the problem is that reloader is true when using this so BackgroundScheduler has two instances.
So how do I stop reloader for Gunicorn?
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: fl]

As you can see in above image 2 processes are created.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can just provide the same arguments as command line arguments in heroku:

`web: gunicorn app:app --reload=False`

This does provide an answer to your question, but it won't solve the issue, as the default value for `--reload` is already `False`. You can check that with `gunicorn --help`.

I think you shouldn't use `BackgroundScheduler`, but instead use the `--daemon` flag. As per `gunicorn --help` :   `-D, --daemon - Daemonize the Gunicorn process. [False]`. "To Daemonize" means run it as a background process.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look into this. I found another working solution for my problem which is to use `--preload` which worked for me.